# converting mysql query with BETWEEN to laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

please advice how to proceed following mysql query for laravel

sql

```
SELECT * FROM shifts
WHERE  time_sheet_id = 11 AND ( "14:00" BETWEEN shift_start_time AND shift_end_time
   OR "15:00" BETWEEN shift_start_time AND shift_end_time
   OR "14:00" >= shift_start_time AND "15:00" <= shift_end_time )
```

this is what i tried

```
 $shiftData = Shifts::where('time_sheet_id', '=', $getTimesheet1->time_sheet_id)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id->user_id)
            ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
            ->whereBetween(Input::get('shift_start_time'), array('shift_start_time ' , 'shift_end_time '))
            ->whereBetween(Input::get('shift_end_time') , array('shift_start_time ' , 'shift_end_time '))
            ->where( Input::get('shift_end_time'), '>=', 'shift_start_time ')
            ->where(Input::get('shift_end_time'), '<=',  'shift_end_time ')
            ->get();
```

and i got this error :( pls advice

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '18:00:00' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `shifts` where `time_sheet_id` = 12 and `user_id` = 2 and `role_id` = 1 and `18:00:00` between shift_start_time and shift_end_time and `20:00:00` between shift_start_time and shift_end_time and `20:00:00` >= shift_start_time and `20:00:00` <= shift_end_time )
```

UPDATE :

```
$shiftData=   DB::table(DB::raw('shifts'))
        ->whereRaw('time_sheet_id = $getTimesheet1->time_sheet_id AND user_id = $user_id->user_id')
        ->whereRaw('Input::get('shift_start_time') BETWEEN shift_start_time AND shift_end_time OR
Input::get('shift_end_time') BETWEEN shift_start_time AND shift_end_time OR
Input::get('shift_start_time') >= shift_start_time AND Input::get('shift_end_time') <= shift_end_time')
        ->count();
```

Comment: My answer doesn't work the way you want, that's why I deleted it. Now I see you want to query for a time between 2 different columns. As far as I know, this can't be done with `whereBetween`. You should use `whereRaw` and replicate your original query.

Comment: what is the data type of shift_start_time ? is it String , Date ? DateTime ? which one ?

Comment: @Tim : can you check the UPDATE part query kindly. i tried with whereRaw. pls advice

Comment: @ogres data type is Time